# How to enable an UI Plugin on CloudStack?

Tags: javascript, maven, jetty, apache-cloudstack

I'm trying to learn to develop plugins for CloudStack and I'm having big problems on viewing that plugin on the CloudStack UI. I cloned the repository from [GitHub](https://github.com/apache/cloudstack) and checkout to 4.9.2.0.

To deploy it, I used this:

```
mvn -pl :cloud-client-ui jetty:run -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.annotations.maxWait=120
```

The CloudStack UI (client) went up and everything is working fine. I modified all the plugins.js that I found at the source code to uncomment this line:

```
cloudStack.plugins = [
    //'testPlugin',
```

When I go the URL of my client, I can't see the testPlugin. If I go to http://10.0.1.9:8080/client/plugins/plugins.js I will still see the testPlugin line commented...

I have restarted the server many times.

To do this, I have followed [this](http://docs.cloudstack.apache.org/en/latest/plugins.html) guide. Specially, this part: "How to Write a Plugin: Implementation Details"

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed it!

Found that there is this file: **plugins.js.gz**... This file is exactly located on **client/target/generated-webapp/scripts/plugins.js.gz**. I renamed it and the jetty started reading the plugins.js.

Thanks everyone!